# Nginx removes removes second slash

Tags: node.js, nginx

I have nginx proxy server for forward request to nodejs server

for example

`http://localhost/api/test//////test` should be forwarded as `test//////test`
So,problem is, Nginx removes duplicate slashes
`http://localhost/api/test//////test` becomes `test/test`

how I can solve this?

nginx config

```
upstream backend_server {
  server backend:4000;
}

server {
  listen 80;
  server_name no_name;

  location /api/ {
    proxy_pass http://backend_server/;
  }

}
```

Nodejs server

```
router.all('*', function(req, res, next) {
  console.log('SERVER WAS REQUESTED url: ' + req.originalUrl);
  request(req.originalUrl.substr(1)).pipe(res)
})
```

Answer (score 0):

So, I find a solution

```
merge_slashes off
```

helps me